# android studio screen turn off / lock screen

Tags: android

when the screen turns off , my scanner wifi turn off too.

how to make the wifi scan persistent ??
I thought to turn on and off the screen to activate the scan wifi but I can not turn off the screen in my service

how to turn screen off or lock screen in the service ?

thank you

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on `AndroidDevelopers` on how to keep the screen on

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    // Do the work that requires your app to keep the CPU running.
    // ...
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    MyWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
}
```

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#java)

Comment: hello, i don't have a probleme for unlock screen, but lock screen do not work